# Rendering a dynamically generated background based on width

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, sass, haml

So I have a background image attribute (as a string referencing an image in the project), that belongs to a Badge table.

I'm rendering each background image based on the current path.  But I want to render different images at two different max-widths.

For example,

```
.badge-headline-background{style: "background-image:url(../assets/header-graphics/#{@badge.background})"}
```

renders a background at full width, while

```
.badge-headline-background{style: "background-image:url(../assets/small-header-graphics/#{@badge.background})"}
```

should use the smaller image once the max-width gets around 700px.

Tweaking the background-position and background-size isn't an option.  It has to be two separate images.

Any input appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: I didn't think you could do this just with CSS, i could be wrong.  I would do it by conditionally adding a class with javascript on pageload and when the element is resized.

Comment: Have you tried using css media queries?

Comment: Plus one for css media queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, using the dynamic value

```
.badge-headline-background

:css
  .badge-headline-background { 
    background-image: url("../assets/header-graphics/#{@badge.background}");
  }
  @media (max-width: 700px) {
    .badge-headline-background { 
      background-image: url("../assets/small-header-graphics/#{@badge.background}");
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.class {background-image: url(whatever-1.jpg);}    
@media (max-width:700px) { .class {background-image: url(whatever-2.jpg;)} }
```